# How to have a range to two input boxes where it will be divided after...

Tags: javascript

I have this 2 input fields which automatically divides the first input by the second one.

First input field:

```
<input type="text" name="MyName1" id="1" value="1000.00" onkeyup="getValues(1)" size="10">
```

Second input field:

```
<input type="text" name="MyName2" id="2" value="26" onkeyup="getValues(2)" size="10">
```

Output:

```
<input type="text" id="main" name="MyOutput" size="5" value=38.46>
```

And my script:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function getValues(val){
        var numVal1=parseFloat(document.getElementById("1").value,10);
        var numVal2=parseFloat(document.getElementById("2").value,10);
        var totalValue = numVal1 / numVal2; 
        document.getElementById("main").value = totalValue.toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
```

How can I add a min/max range for both input fields so that the only range accepted on the first input field will be from 200-1000, and the second input field will be from 1-26. An alert would be also cool if the value is not within the specified range.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Shopping list? How much do you pay?

Comment: you can put validation for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a simple interval-bound check:

```
function getValues(val){
var numVal1=parseFloat(document.getElementById("1").value,10);
var numVal2=parseFloat(document.getElementById("2").value,10);
var totalValue = numVal1 / numVal2; 
if(numVal1 >= 200 && numVal1 <= 1000){
  document.getElementById("1").style.borderColor='red';
}else{
  document.getElementById("1").style.borderColor='';
}
if(numVal2>= 1&& numVal2 <= 26){
  document.getElementById("2").style.borderColor='red';
}else{
  document.getElementById("2").style.borderColor='';
}
document.getElementById("main").value = totalValue.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: It's almost working!!! When I change the default value from 1000 to something, the alert pops up for every keystroke I make. :( Can the alert pops up after an onBlur or something? Thanks for the effort mightyuhu!!! :)

Comment: @francoom then replace ur onkeyup event to onblur event in ur html

Comment: Exactly, a good practice is not to use alerts but to highlight the field red or what gives

Comment: I have changed it to onBlur but the alert pops up if I click anything outside the browser and haven't changed the values. Sorry.

Comment: Wow, that is what I want. I'd rather highlight the field in red. Can you please show me how? please???

Comment: @francoom - Wow, you didn't even have to put a cherry on top.

Comment: Hi mightyuhu, the field turns red even if I type in a value less than 1000. I'm sorry. :(

Comment: Oh, I think you reversed it, but I interchange the condition already. border.Color='' should be if >=200 && <= 1000, else, red. Yes, it is working. Thank you so much mightyuhu for the effort and thank you all for all your efforts!!! :)